# Float - how to prevent from wrapping around

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am not sure how to name my problem, so please see the diagram below:

```
+------------+
|            | <li>lorem ipsum dolor blah blah
|   image    | blah blah blah blah blah blah
|            | blah blah blah blah blah </li>
|            | <li> Blah blah blah blah blah
+------------+ blah blah blah blah blah blah
               blah blah blah blah blah blah
               blah blah blah blah blah </li>
<li>Lorem ispum dolor blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah</li>
```

Basically, I want the text to wrap around the image but if first line of a paragraph/list is next to the image I want the whole item to be left aligned to the first line even if there is space below image to fill.

Image has `float: left;`

Tried playing with `display`, `widows` and `orphans` properties but it didn't work.

Comment: You should wrap your text in a `<p>` element and float that left also.

Comment: My code (in its pure form) is almost identical to this fiddle (created by @Ayman Safadi) http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/gPmag/ I played with some properties but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make it working in pure CSS so I've used some Javascript:

```
var $img = $("img");
var imageBottom = $img.position().top + $img.height();
var desiredMargin = $img.position().left + $img.width();

$("li").each(function(){
    if ($(this).position().top < imageBottom)
    {
        $(this).css("margin-left", desiredMargin);
    }
});
```

The working sample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/yVnNr/
The drawback is that layout re-flows after page load (unless the image dimensions are specified in the code).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

**HTML**

```
<div class="some-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
    <ul>
        <li>FIRST ipsum dolor blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </li>
        <li>SECOND blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </li>
        <li>THIRD ispum dolor blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
        <li>FOURTH ipsum dolor blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </li>
        <li>FIFTH blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </li>
        <li>SIXTH ispum dolor blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    float: left;
}
ul, li {
    display: inline;
}
li:after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}​
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/gPmag/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it's not working for me. The result I am after is similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/gEk7s/1/ (but without the need of defining margins for individual entries)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Sample Page</title>

  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .clearfix {
      *zoom: 1;
    }
    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
      display: table;
      content: "";
      line-height: 0;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
      clear: both;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style ="width:600px;">
    <img src="http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s480x480/253488_482594598432035_2073442784_n.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100px;"/>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 340px;">
    <li>lorem ipsum dolor blah blah
     blah blah blah blah blah blah
     blah blah blah blah blah </li>

     <li> Blah blah blah blah blah
     blah blah blah blah blah blah
                   blah blah blah blah blah blah
                   blah blah blah blah blah </li>
    <li>Lorem ispum dolor blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum dolor blah blah
     blah blah blah blah blah blah
     blah blah blah blah blah </li>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mahsa_999/zhAG2/)

```
<img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/5pfk05.jpg"/>
<ul>
    <li>lorem ipsum dolor blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah </li>
    <li>lorem ipsum dolor blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah </li>
    <li>lorem ipsum dolor blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah </li>

</ul>

img
{
   width:200px;
   height: 200px;
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
}

ul{
   margin: 15px ;
}
```